Formatting the input file with Sed to Output but generating empty gilr
I’m having an input file with one million records and formatting and writing to another file to a different location but some times it is writing empty file(intermittent).
Following is the scenario:
Input.out
Adding Header: echo "HSample" >> output.out
Details : cat Input.out | sed -e 's/^/D/' >> output.out
Trailer : echo "TSample" >> output.out

In the output.out it is writing only Trailer record without header and details.
This is happening intermittently, if I rerun it is ok.

Please do not cross-post. For the record, another copy is on Super User.

The problem is almost certainly in some other part of your code that you haven't shown us. Always provide a minimal, complete, program that demonstrates your problem.

yet another copy is on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79154132/formatting-with-sed-giving-an-empty-file

Nothing in those 3 lines of code can explain why you'd be missing the header, but in any case, you don't need to open output.out each time nor concatenate a single file.
{
  echo HSample
  < input.out sed 's/^/D/'
  echo TSample
} > output.out

(or >> instead of > if you want to append the output of those 3 commands at the end as opposed to making it the contents of output.out).
Note that input.out and output.out cannot be the same file.
You could also change it to:
{
  echo HSample
  sed 's/^/D/'
  echo TSample
} < input.out > output.out

To avoid creating/overwriting output.out at all (or appending anything to it with >>) if input.out cannot be opened for a reason or another.
See also paste -dD /dev/null input.out as a likely much faster way to prepend D to each line of input.out (paste -dD /dev/null - to apply it to stdin).
